# Auth failing - 999- HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, http-status-codes

I using [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), and I would like to get Ignoring response URL.I just see in the output console this:

DEBUG: Ignoring response <999 https://www.mywebsite.com>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed.

Comment: What broken software is generating that?

Comment: Yahoo Fantasy Football returns 999 when you do too many requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spider-middleware.html) you can add a list of HTTP status codes which should be handled by your spider even if they are not allowed by default.

In your case you have to add following line to your spider definition:

```
handle_httpstatus_list = [999]
```

This will cause the spider to get the result even with this status code.

**Next time** before asking a question pleas look through StackOverflow for similar questions and read the docs. And it won't be wrong to put some code to let us know where is your error happening. Without this information it is seldom that the community can give any answers.

Comment: @Nareshkumar: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.