# Scrapy spider login issue

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a beginner using scrapy and I meet this issue towards logging in. I just put all the form data into the FormRequest.

My code:

```
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider

class login_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'login_spider'

    FORM = {"_xsrf":"776a978b48e9e828a939c096ae9b787e",
        "password":"...",
        "captcha_type":"cn",
        "email":"...",
       }

    COOKIES = {
    "q_c1":"201afdf74fab4f538d15fd8726c1fe14|1480730632000|1480730632000", 
    "_xsrf":"776a978b48e9e828a939c096ae9b787e",
    "l_cap_id":"MDE2MzhmNGUwN2FjNDA1ZTk3NDc5ZDZkZmJhMzM3Y2M=|1480730632|83da14e1526864adfa6e0bec5a9f49bf46f8c460",
           "cap_id":"OGY2MWMzODIxY2VmNGQ4MGExOTk4N2UwNzU1OWFlYzM=|1480730632|77b6eaaca21f9c96ecfa5d5c9832e34dc2e401e0",
    "d_c0":"ADDCXsSu8AqPTuqHLcmhlUeOsUY-UBuyRL0=|1480730633", 
        "r_cap_id":"Mjg0YTg2NTcxMjAxNDU2YTljZGNhMjQ1MzVlMjE4ZmI=|1480730633|cd2007eb5d1c6939ac1954b79b83f0d7b5d9e937",
    "_zap":"57aed33d-98b6-4e98-bad4-71581265abde",
    "__utmt":1,
    "__utma":"51854390.1175567315.1480730634.1480730634.1480730634.1", 
    "__utmb":"51854390.4.10.1480730634",
    "__utmc":"51854390",
    "__utmz":"51854390.1480730634.1.1.utmcsr=bing|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)",
    "__utmv":"51854390.000--|3=entry_date=20161203=1",
    "n_c":1,
}

    HEADERS = {
    "Accept":"*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Connection":"keep-alive",
    "Content-Length":"100",
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host":"www.zhihu.com",
    "Origin":"https://www.zhihu.com",
    "Referer":"https://www.zhihu.com/",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-Xsrftoken":"776a978b48e9e828a939c096ae9b787e",
}

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(url="https://www.zhihu.com/#signin", callback=self.login)]

    def login(self, response):
        return [FormRequest(
            "https://www.zhihu.com/#signin",
            formdata=self.FORM,
            cookies=self.COOKIES,
            headers=self.HEADERS,
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_filter=True
        )]

    def after_login(self, response):
        print("================\n")
        print("=== LOG IN ===\n")
        print("================\n")
```

I get the form data from here:
[image: The email % pwd are randomly created]

And I get these:

```
2016-12-03 11:07:07 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-12-03 11:07:07 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-03 11:07:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2016-12-03 11:07:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.zhihu.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-12-03 11:07:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.zhihu.com/#signin> (referer: None)
2016-12-03 11:07:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://www.zhihu.com/#signin> (referer: https://www.zhihu.com/) ['partial']
2016-12-03 11:07:08 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <400 https://www.zhihu.com/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2016-12-03 11:07:08 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Then I tried this, adding these codes in setting.py:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"
RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [400,403,500]
RETRY_TIMES = 2
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,}
```

Yet I still get the same error. I don't know what should I do. So what part am I doing wrongly and what kind of changes should I apply?

Comment: It looks like your issue is given by the line `Ignoring response <400 https://www.zhihu.com/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779766/auth-failing-999-http-status-code-is-not-handled-or-not-allowed). You'll also want to check your request as an issue with the request could be indicated by a 400 response.

Answer (score 1):

Status code 400 is sometimes returned when an invalid CSRF token is provided.  CSRF tokens change each time a page is visited, and it appears you have hard coded a static token.   Your script will need to make an initial request to the page with the login form, save the CSRF token in a variable and then log in.